# Access to Flex application parameters in an SDK-independent way

Tags: apache-flex

I have a library of Flex components that is used by both SDK 3 and 4 projects. Since most of the code is the same, it would be useless to split into two libraries and duplicate most of the classes. I have a compilation problem, though, with access to application parameters. Unfortunately things have changed from version 3 to 4, from Application.application.parameters to FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters. Now, mx.core.Application is still available in SDK 4 (although deprecated) but mx.core.FlexGlobals is NOT available in SDK 3. This makes my library not compilable when linked to Flex 3 projects.
A possible solution would be to move SDK-dependent logic to the calling projects, then injecting parameters into the library components, but that would break library encapsulation so I am wondering whether there is a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [conditional compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html). But you must be aware of this restriction:

> You cannot use constant Boolean values to conditionalize metadata or
>   import statements.

But if you use an import like this

```
import mx.core.*
```

you can possible workaround this limitation.